# Flagging comments should be localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, localization, international-sites

It seems like comments generated by flagging are not localized.

1) go on Русский язык stack exchange  https://rus.stackexchange.com/

2) flag a question as a duplicate of some other question

3) see a comment like "does this answer your question [link to question]" instead of "вот этот вопрос похож на ваш [link to question]"

I haven't tried it, I just saw a comment in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already translated in Traducir, string https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13674.

We have topic about it on ruSO: [Нет перевода текста в комментариях при закрытии вопроса как дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9947/15479).

You will see the translated string, when a new revision is released (last one was `rev 2019.12.20.35703`).